Why my CustomSecurityExpressionRoot and mycustom method is not recognized as a security expression?
i am trying to implement a custom security expression in my springboot app.
i wrote these classes:
SecurityAccessService:
@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SecurityAccessService {
    public boolean hasAccess(String actionNames, Authentication authentication) {
        List<String> actionsItem = Arrays.asList(actionNames.split(","));
        System.out.println("method has been invoked with these arguments "+actionsItem);
        System.out.println("the authentication object is this  "+authentication);
        return true;
    }
}

CustomSecurityExpressionRoot:


public class CustomSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {
    private Object filterObject;
    private Object returnObject;
    private SecurityAccessService securityAccessService;

    public CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
    }


    public boolean hasAccess(String actionName) {
        return this.securityAccessService.hasAccess(actionName, getAuthentication());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFilterObject() {
        return this.filterObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getReturnObject() {
        return this.returnObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getThis() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterObject(Object obj) {
        this.filterObject = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReturnObject(Object obj) {
        this.returnObject = obj;
    }

    public void setSecurityAccessService(SecurityAccessService securityAccessService) {
        this.securityAccessService = securityAccessService;
    }
}


CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler:
@Component
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityAccessService securityAccessService;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication,MethodInvocation invocation) {
        CustomSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setSecurityAccessService(securityAccessService);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        this.applicationContext=applicationContext;
    }
}

and finally MethodSecurityConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true,securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return expressionHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
        var expresionAdvice= new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
        expresionAdvice.setExpressionHandler(getExpressionHandler());
        decisionVoters.add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expresionAdvice));
        decisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
        return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
    }
}

Now in my controller, i am using my custom security expression like this :
   @GetMapping("/all")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAccess('test')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<MyDTO>> findAllDTOs(Authentication authentication) {
        return new ResponseEntity(dtoService.findAllDtos(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

in postman when i invoke this API, i get
    "cause": {
        "cause": null,
 "expressionString": null,
        "position": 0,
        "message": "EL1004E: Method call: Method hasAccess(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot",
        "inserts": [
            "hasAccess(java.lang.String)",
            "org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot"
        ],
        "messageCode": "METHOD_NOT_FOUND",
        "simpleMessage": "EL1004E: Method call: Method hasAccess(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot",
        "suppressed": [],
        "localizedMessage": "EL1004E: Method call: Method hasAccess(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot"
    },

i tried creating a Bean that returns my "CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler "  in my SecurityConfiguration class but this doesn't work.
this my securityConfig class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.jwk-set-uri}")
    private String jwkSetUri;
    @Bean
    public CustomKeycloakConverter customKeycloakConverter() {
        return new CustomKeycloakConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder decode() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder =
                new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        httpSecurity.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger-ui.html")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger/**")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger-ui/**")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/v3/api-docs/**")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/health")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.GET, "/info")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")).permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                ).oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(customKeycloakConverter())));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }
}


i found an other solution using this :
    @PreAuthorize("@serviceName.hasAccess('test')")

but we have to use the first method
